# Efficient way to delete lines from a file in python (and keep the same file name)?

Tags: python, file

My program is keeping a log for the user.  If the log ever gets bigger than a set amount, I want to delete the first 20% of lines.

From similar questions, I've seen suggestions to do read in the old file, and write out all the lines I want to keep into a new file.  However, my files might be too large to be constantly reading them in, and using that method wouldn't let me keep the same file name.

Can I delete lines from a file without reading in my old file?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to remove from the beginning of a file without opening it and reading it.  If there is, I'm interested to know how to do so.

Comment: That method would certainly let you keep the same file name. Just read it, close the file, and reopen it for writing.

Comment: How big are these files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general method to achieve this for logfiles is 'rotation' - when the logfiles gets older or hits a certain size, you rename it and start writing a new one.
If you are using [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, there is even a preconfigured one - [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) that does this automatically.

As for your question: you can only truncate from the back, not from the beginning. An approximate solution would be to seek() to 20% of the file, find first '\n' and copy it out - but it will be slow and prone to race conditions. Go with logging and RotatingFileHandler.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the traditional way to solve this problem is to keep 5 different files instead of 1 large one. When you need to delete 20%, just delete the oldest file and rename the others.

As handy as text files are, you might also consider a database. It is designed to be able to delete any part of the data at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if size > MAX_SIZE:
    f = open(your_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    f = open(your_file, 'w')
    f.write('\n'.join(lines[len(lines)/5:]))
    f.close()
```

That might do it. Although, as the first two said, it's much better to use multiple files or even a DB if you can. **This code is not tested.**